# Regex to find text in meta

Tags: regex

What is the regex with PHP to find the content of "session" in "URL" in this variable :

```
$var = "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/game/index.php?page=overview&session=9efae87dd67&lgn=1'>"
```

Thanks :)

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: `(?<=&session=)[\da-f]*`?

Comment: This doesn't work :

Comment: $test = "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/game/index.php?page=overview&session=123456&lgn=1'>";
$pattern = '(?<=&session=)[\da-f]*';
preg_match($pattern, $test, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
die;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your regexp.

```
preg_match("/session=(\\w+)/", $var, $session);
echo $session[1]; // => "9efae87dd67"
```

Answer (score 1):

Really, use a `DOM` parser **combined** with regular expressions, like so:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/game/index.php?page=overview&session=9efae87dd67&lgn=1'>
<body/>
DATA;

$previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$meta = $xpath->query("//meta")->item(0);

$regex = '~session=\K[^&]+~';
preg_match($regex, $meta->getAttribute("content"), $session);
echo $session[0];

libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value);

?>
```

---

And see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/6wwtI0).

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex: `(?<=&session=)[\da-zA-Z]*`

You'll also need to escape special html characters in PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:session=)\w+
```

Although I find it easier on the mind to use capturing parenthesis:

```
session=(\w+)
```

In the last case you will need to access match no. 1